# What is start angle and end angle of arc in html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm learning HTML5 and I"m stuck on arc.

syntax

```
arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise)
```

I'm not getting this startAngle,endAngle perfectly how this two parameters are calculated to
draw different types of circles,arcs?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This method takes **Six** parameters:

- x and y are the coordinates of the circle's center.
- Radius is self  explanatory.
- The *startAngle* and *endAngle* parameters define the  start and end points of the arc in  radians. The starting and closing angle are measured from the x axis.
- The anticlockwise parameter is a boolean value which when true draws the arc anticlockwise, otherwise in a clockwise direction.

For better understanding of  startAngle and endAngle

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-arcs/

[image: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/html5_canvas_arc6.png]

Comment: Weird the clockwise is default, since that goes against mathematical convention.

Answer (score 4):

They are radians, not degrees.

[Some good examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/2_4_canvas_arc.html)

Answer (score 3):

I looked into a few answers and was very confused by degrees and radians so I drew an image when I tested using html5 canvas. Hope this one help you understand easily.

If you are more familiar with number than formulas with PI,then
The answer to put in the parameter is simply between **0-6.2831** approximately (2π,360°)

and it doesn't take either "**π**" or **degrees(180°)**
[image: an image to understand startAngle/endAngle]

Comment: also the original code file is uploaded to:[github files](https://github.com/32802446/startAngle-endAngle-test)